# How do I properly sort this array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created a couple arrays. arrLocations holds a series of 2-digit country names, arrResults counts how many times each occurs and holds the country name with it's count as see here:

```
[
  FR: 40,  US: 1511, AU: 82,
  CN: 151, IE: 170,  SG: 108,
  GB: 66,  KR: 52,   JP: 137,
  IN: 45,  BR: 68,   SE: 39,
  ZA: 19,  NL: 19,   BH: 19,
  LU: 3,   CA: 41,   DE: 79,
  ID: 1,   HK: 1
]
```

My intention is to sort this array by ascending occurrence, I want this:

```
[
  ID: 1,  HK: 1,  LU: 3,
  BH: 19, NL: 19, ZA: 19,
  ....and so on........
]
```

However, no matter what way I implement sort, it does absolutely nothing. I even did a test sort on a dumby array and was able to sort it fine, but this array I cannot sort.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var geoip = require('geoip-lite')
const fs = require('fs')
const { Console } = require('console')
let data = fs.readFileSync('./ip_new.txt')
let iplocation = ""
let arrLocations = []
let arrResults = []

let arrIP = data.toString().split("\r\n")

for(let item of arrIP){
iplocation = geoip.lookup(item)
arrLocations.push(iplocation.country)
}

for(let item of arrLocations){
if (item in arrResults){
    arrResults[item]++
}
else{
    arrResults[item]=1
}
}

arrResults.sort()
console.log(arrResults)
```

Comment: Neither one of your  first two data structures are array syntax in Javascript.  Do you mean plain objects instead of arrays or do you mean arrays of objects?  Arrays have a list of elements.  Objects have property/value pairs.  If so, objects don't have an ability to sort their property list.  Properties are enumerated in the order they were created.

Comment: your information structures do not exist in javascript, which makes your question completely absurd

Comment: @MisterJojo You're almost certainly correct, but I want to mention that if you do `let x = []; x.FR = 40; x.US = 1511; x.AU = 82; console.log(x)`  you'll see output that matches what was written.  Furthermore, if you add the properties in a different order, you'll see them "sorted".  `let y = []; y.FR = 40; y.AU = 82; y.US = 1511; console.log(y)`  Again, I concede this is almost certainly not what @AdamCambell is asking. But your comment that the structures "do not exist" made me think of this. I realize it's log formatting, not JavaScript syntax that achieves this.

Comment: @Wyck in the case of `let x = []; x.FR=40; x.US = 1511...` make an empty array => `console.log(x.length)` is **zero**.

Comment: Please don't post a question and then disappear.  That's not how this place works.  Your question is accumulating both downvotes and closevotes because it's unclear and you are not engaging to clarify the problems.  Your question will probably be closed soon.  If you do this regularly, you could lose your ability to post questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so first of all I'm assuming this

```js
[
  FR: 40,  US: 1511, AU: 82,
  CN: 151, IE: 170,  SG: 108,
  GB: 66,  KR: 52,   JP: 137,
  IN: 45,  BR: 68,   SE: 39,
  ZA: 19,  NL: 19,   BH: 19,
  LU: 3,   CA: 41,   DE: 79,
  ID: 1,   HK: 1
]
```

Is actually this

```js
[
    { FR: 40 },  { US: 1511 }, { AU: 82 },
    { CN: 151 }, { IE: 170 },  { SG: 108 },
    { GB: 66 },  { KR: 52 },   { JP: 137 },
    { IN: 45 },  { BR: 68 },   { SE: 39 },
    { ZA: 19 },  { NL: 19 },   { BH: 19 },
    { LU: 3 },   { CA: 41 },   { DE: 79 },
    { ID: 1 },   { HK: 1 }
]
```

If this is true, then sort method will not work on it's own. The following will do though:

```
const arrResults = [
    { FR: 40 },  { US: 1511 }, { AU: 82 },
    { CN: 151 }, { IE: 170 },  { SG: 108 },
    { GB: 66 },  { KR: 52 },   { JP: 137 },
    { IN: 45 },  { BR: 68 },   { SE: 39 },
    { ZA: 19 },  { NL: 19 },   { BH: 19 },
    { LU: 3 },   { CA: 41 },   { DE: 79 },
    { ID: 1 },   { HK: 1 }
];

arrResults.sort((a, b) => {
    const countryCodeA = Object.keys(a)[0];
    const countryCodeB = Object.keys(b)[0];

    return a[countryCodeA] - b[countryCodeB];
});
```